# Send php data to html page

Tags: php, html

I have two `html` pages that include `php` part and I want to send php value from first html page to second html page. Normally it's like... `/page2.php?uid=$uid` but my pages' extension is not `.php`, it is `.html` but its include php part. So how can I do it please?

Thank you all I just change all html pages to php pages.

Comment: how about sessions? and you can still use a form and variables in the url regardless of the page(file) extension

Comment: Possibly try factoring out the code that depends on that variable you want to send into a separate php file to be included with `include` or `require` directives.

Comment: How do you include the PHP part??

Comment: uid is different user id , I mean another session

Comment: @Repox I tried <html> <body> <?php .... ?> </body> </html> like that

Comment: @OznOzi I don't get it. You are using PHP in files with .html extension?

Comment: Can you post some code snippet here?

Comment: @Repox yes whats wrong ?

Comment: @OznOzi Unless your server setup specifies that files with .html extension can be parsed as PHP, that wouldn't work.

Comment: @OznOzi if you use `.html` as your file extension and include `php` code in it, the php code will not be executed... you have to change the extension to php... I don't see any reason behind using `.html` instead of `.php` here...

Comment: @BlackCobra ok I changed it but now I have one question; I want to send $row['id'] value to other php page. How can I do that?

Comment: @OznOzi happy to know that you have a question for me... are you redirecting the user from the first page to the second page...??

Comment: @BlackCobra I get some info from sql and I stored it on $row[] , now I want to sent $row['id'] to another page. This is question.

Comment: Friend you don't understand me... however, if your first page don't have any html code means not displaying anything then use `require()` method after you build the `$row[]` array... this way the second page will get the `$row[]` array by default... you don't have to do anything... but if the situation is like that user open the first file... do something... then open the send page... then you have to use another method... what is your situation...??

Comment: @OznOzi did I solve your problem...??

Comment: I just ask to everyone then I solved and also Thank you for your help friend

Comment: @OznOzi you are welcome... then please post the answer and accept it to close this question...

Answer (score 0):

Send your value like this:

file_1.php

```
<a href="file_2.php?var=variable">send</a>
```

file_2.php

```
<?php
    $variable = $_GET['var'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

best way is to use rewrite in your .htaccess file :

```
rewrite /(.*)-([0-9]+).html$ $1.php?uid=$2 [nc,L]
```

if you type in url :

```
/page-58.html
```

then your php file must be

```
page.php
```

and you can get input value as `$_GET['uid']` that was 58 in this case .